# Difference between logical line and physical line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reading and i got these two terms and i am confused as in logical line it says "The end of a logical line is represented by the token NEWLINE".
Newline means go to the next line which eventually ends the line.

And in physical line its written "A physical line is a sequence of characters terminated by an end-of-line sequence". so the same thing happens when we use newline with logical line. so what is the difference?

the link is 'https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#logical-lines'

Comment: Do you have a link to where you're seeing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from the Python documentation regarding [lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html).

Here is one logical and physical line:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here is one logical line on two physical lines:

```
my_list = [1, 2,
           3, 4]
```

Comment: but the second one has invalid syntax if i am not wrong

Comment: Hi @MayankSharma that second example has a valid syntax. You can check that. The compiler doesn't give any error. 

We can say that is not a good practice of writing the code. TigerhawkT3 ( One who answered ) has wrote the code like that to make the us understand the difference between physical and logical new line

Hope you got. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you write a program , what you see is considered to be a `physical line`.

`Logical line` refers to a single statement what python sees.

An example of a logical line is a statement like print 'Hello World!'.

Answer (score 0):

Two or more physical lines may be joined into logical lines using backslash characters (), as follows: when a physical line ends in a backslash that is not part of a string literal or comment, it is joined with the following forming a single logical line, deleting the backslash and the following end-of-line character.

```
if 1900 < year < 2100 and 1 <= month <= 12 \
and 1 <= day <= 31 and 0 <= hour < 24 \
and 0 <= minute < 60 and 0 <= second < 60:   # Looks like a valid date
return 1
```

**Remember:**

- A line ending in a backslash cannot carry a comment.
- A backslash does not continue a comment.
- A backslash does not continue a token except for string literals (i.e., tokens other than string literals cannot be split across physical lines using a backslash).
- A backslash is illegal elsewhere on a line outside a string literal.