# python ParseError: Bad Input on line

Tags: python, parsing, input, calculator

ok so I a trying to make a calculator in python and it comes up with ParseError: Bad Input on line 7 and ParseError: Bad Input on line 6 etc. all the way down to ParseError: Bad Input on line 1, can anyone spot the error and how to fix it.

```
     1:) n = input(" select first number: ")
     2:) d = raw_input("What operation: ")
     3:) print " What operation: " + str(d)
     4:) n1 = input(" select second number ")

     6:) if d == "+":
     7:) print "Did you know that " + str(n) + " plus " + str(n1) + " is "
     7:) + str(n+n1)+ "?"
     8:)
     9:)print " "
     10:)print "Goodbye"
```

Comment: Please could you edit your code to take line numbers out and insert proper indentation?

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
print "Did you know that " + str(n) + " plus " + str(n1) + " is "
```

will happily print something. Then the interpreter sees this:

```
+ str(n+n1)+ "?"
```

and has no idea what you mean, because it doesn't know you're continuing the previous line's `print` statement. You can fix this by adding parentheses:

```
>>> print ("Did you know that " + str(1) + " plus " + str(1) + " is "
... + str(2)+ "?")
Did you know that 1 plus 1 is 2?
```

Now the interpreter knows that, when you finish that first line, you're not done entering the expression. It will wait for you to finish a valid statement before processing it. See also [logical lines and physical lines in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572589/difference-between-logical-line-and-physical-line-in-python).